# How to add custom filed name 'mobile number' in customer registration form in magento 2?

Tags: php, magento

I want to add mobile number field in customer registration page. And also want to display that field in admin site customer listing page.

For that I don't want to change in core file. May I create my own extension for that ? If yes then how can i do that please guide me, I am new in magento.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184006/how-to-add-new-fields-on-registration-page-in-magento2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49049011/add-custom-attribute-in-magento-2/49385883#49385883

Answer (score -1):

Please go to stores->configuration->customer configuration and enable mobile number.