# Add custom attribute in magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to add a custom field to the frontend registration form.
I already added required feilds in database by following

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
        'sample_attribute',
        [
            'type'         => 'varchar',
            'label'        => 'Sample Attribute',
            'input'        => 'text',
            'required'     => false,
            'visible'      => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position'     => 999,
            'system'       => 0,
        ]
    );
    $sampleAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'sample_attribute');

    // more used_in_forms ['adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address']
    $sampleAttribute->setData(
        'used_in_forms',
        ['adminhtml_customer']

    );
    $sampleAttribute->save();
}
```

my feild listed in magento admin. I'm unable to display it in frontend

Answer (score 1):

The path of *customer_account_create.xml* should be `Vendor_Module\view\frontend\layout\`.

For those who are new to **Magento** and do not know about all the filename and filepath conventions to be precise is very important to avoid spending time searching for errors.

Answer (score 0):

first thing that comes to my eyes is that attributes are created just for the backend, if you set

```
'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer']
```

only, it will display only in backend. You at least have to add

```
'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 
'customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address']
```

but you should post also the code of your register form in frontend

Answer (score 0):

To add additional field in a customer account

**Vendor_Module\layout\customer_account_create.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="my_form_additional_info_customer" template="Vendor_Module::additionalinfocustomer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Vendor_Module\view\frontend\templates\additionalinfocustomer.phtml**

```
<fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Additional Information') ?></span></legend>
    <p>
    <div class="field regulation required">
        <label for="Mobile" class="label">
            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Mobile Number') ?></span>
        </label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" name="mobile_number" id="mobile_number" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Mobile Number') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}">
        </div>
    </div>
</p>
</fieldset>
```

**Vendor_Module\Setup\InstallData.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2018 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * Install data
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface {

    /**
     * CustomerSetupFactory
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * $attributeSetFactory
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * initiate object
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
    CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory, AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * install data method
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
        /**
         * customer registration form default field mobile number
         */
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile_number', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Mobile Number',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);
        //add attribute to attribute set
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile_number')
                ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address', 'checkout_register', 'adminhtml_checkout'],
        ]);
        $attribute->save();
    }

}
```

After that run Below Commands:

- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento cache:flush